# python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 on amazon AMI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

After pouring over thread after thread regarding this issue I still cannot get rid of this error.

I have a Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03.1 x86_64 HVM GP2 set up on AWS.

When trying to run

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

I get the Egg_info Code 1 Error

I have tried:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
sudo pip install ez_setup
```

Further, I ran the ez_setup.py file as suggested but can't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by using the

```
pip install mysql-connector-repackaged
```

package.  This is replacing trying to use MySQLdb